# Layouts inside fragment not rendering

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have an `Fragment Layout` which loads fine but the elements of the layout are been added programatically because I don't know how many tabs I need for this layout.

My problem is that I can get the child count of the Linear Layout and they are all supposed to be added but nothing is displayed :(

Here is what I tried:

- Tried using TableRow, TableLayout, Relative Layout, Creating another Linear Layout inside, etc.. Some of those options would display only ONE child instead of the 16 that are supposed to be displayed
- Tried setting the Width of the buttons manually in XML and through Layout Params. The button is displayed BUT only ONE button.

Here is the code for my onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.descriptive_tables_tabs, null, true);
    tabsLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myTabsRow);
    args = this.getArguments();
    toLoadTabs = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.toLoadTable);
    tabButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    tabTitles = args.getStringArrayList("tabTitles");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Tabs Title Size: " + tabTitles.size());
    float weight = 1.0f / tabTitles.size();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "WEIGHT: " + weight);
    for (String s : tabTitles) {
        Button mButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_button, null, true);
        View separator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.separator, null, true);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight);
        mButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        mButton.setText(s);
        tabButtons.add(mButton);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Tabs: " + s);
        tabsLayout.addView(mButton);
        tabsLayout.addView(separator);
    }
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Layout Childs: " + tabsLayout.getChildCount());
    return view;
}
```

Here is the LOGCAT info that shows that the data is being passed and the childs exist..

```
06-02 17:47:37.314  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs Title Size: 8
06-02 17:47:37.314  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ WEIGHT: 0.125
06-02 17:47:37.319  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: FlyingHours
06-02 17:47:37.319  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: QuantityPerAssembly
06-02 17:47:37.319  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: UseFactor
06-02 17:47:37.319  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: Failures
06-02 17:47:37.319  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: ManHours
06-02 17:47:37.324  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: Aborts
06-02 17:47:37.324  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: MeanTimeBetweenFailures
06-02 17:47:37.324  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Tabs: RepairAndMaintenanceCritical
06-02 17:47:37.324  14000-14000/com.example.sbirafphase2 I/DESCRIPTIVE TABLES FRAGMENT﹕ Layout Childs: 16
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem, the gray area is where my tabs are supposed to go :(
[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem]

Thanks!

EDIT - Adding the XML layouts that are been used:

descriptive_tables_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myTabsRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:background="@color/light_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="93"
        android:background="@color/light_bg">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/loadTabFrag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the tab_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_button_selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="changeTab"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:text="@string/model_information"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue_bg"
    android:textSize="@dimen/tab_title" />
```

EDIT: The layout itself is not rendering at all. The background of the tabs row should be white and match the rest of the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.... For some reason the Layout was only accepting one child (or was only rendering it because the child count was 16....) 
SO what I did was use a `TableLayout` for the the `R.id.myTabsRow;`

And inside my Fragment `onCreateView` I created a `TableRow` and added all the childs to the `TableRow` and after the loop I added the row to the `TableLayout` and now everything is rendering fine!!

Here is my final Working code in case it is helpful to someone:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    args = this.getArguments();
    tabTitles = args.getStringArrayList("tabTitles");
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.descriptive_tables_tabs, null);
    tabsLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myTabsRow);

    toLoadTabs = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.toLoadTable);
    tabButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    //ArrayList<DescriptiveTablesFragment> tables = (DescriptiveTablesFragment) args.getParcelableArrayList("tables");

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Tabs Title Size: " + tabTitles.size());
    float weight = 1f;
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "WEIGHT: " + weight);

    TableRow myRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
    myRow.setWeightSum((float) tabTitles.size());
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight);
    for (String s : tabTitles) {
        Button mButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_button, null);
        View separator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.separator, null);
        mButton.setText(s);
        mButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        tabButtons.add(mButton);
        myRow.addView(mButton);
        myRow.addView(separator);
    }
    tabsLayout.addView(myRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the xml of `R.layout.descriptive_tables_tabs`, but the problem must be with `R.id.myTabsRow`.

For instance, if width was set to `wrap_content`, it would be invisible. This is because the child views are set to 0 width with a weight. This will only claim the space available, which will be 0 in this case.

**Edit:**

From the added xml, it seems that the problem is indeed in R.id.myTabsRow:

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

Setting this to wrap_content should solve it.

Comment: I don't believe that is the problem because the width of R.id.myTabsRow is defined as match_parent with an weight of "1". That is why I set the weight of the buttons when I define them so I know how wide each button should be to fit the screen.

Comment: In any case, add the xml of descriptive_tables_tabs to your question. And actually, perhaps it would be best to add all the used xml files.

Comment: Added the 2 layouts that are being used.

Comment: I edited my answer. I know you already solved it in a different way, but I would like to know anyway if this was the problem.